# USB 3.0 Ethernet adapter outperforms motherboard PCIe GBE

Tags: iperf

I recently did three different Iperf bandwidth tests using various network adapters. **My question is: How does a USB 3.0 ethernet adapter outperform a built in gigabit ethernet controller on the motherboard?** In the tests, I took screen shots of the results and calculated the minimum and maximum bandwidth results and put together a Word document for the experiment.

Take a look at the experiment documentation on my Google Drive for specifics about the equipment used. [Bandwidth Testing - Google Drive Document](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B712Ka9xvuVydlJxSndMZ1VNclE)

**The conclusion**

> The fastest network adapter on the client side is the USB 3.0 Ethernet
>   adapter.  This is surprising to me because a USB peripheral
>   outperforms both the PCI and the PCIe network adapters that are
>   attached to the motherboard.  The USB Ethernet adapter outperformed
>   the built in PCIe network adapter by 17.125 megabytes per second and
>   the PCI network adapter by 50.625 megabytes per second.  The test
>   results are unable to conclude that the Thunderbolt Ethernet adapter
>   is faster than the USB Ethernet adapter at this time.

Comment: In the case #2, something clearly is wrong. Set the Network Mode/ Speed and Duplex mode to 1000 Mbps Full Duplex. Update the driver, retry the test.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that PCI/PCIE Realtek based ethernet adapters are about as low-end as you can get.   If you were instead got an in Intel or even broadcom adapter it would perform as well as - or outperform the USB adapter (the USB adapter was pretty close to maximum speed)

Here is a [forum](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/18497) post - which starts with a copy-and-paste of comments for the freeBSD realtek driver which explains why its so slow.  Basically it has very little logic or decent buffers on it on it and is extremely CPU intensive.  I acknowledge that this is for an older card, however Realtek chipset nics are pretty much always considered to be cheap.  (Without knowing the model - its hard to investigate further).     You might be able to improve things somewhat with better drivers - maybe.

Comment: I updated the drivers on the motherboard's LAN chipset and the speed went up to ~950 Mbit/sec but the Linksys PCI card remains at ~500Mbit/sec.